# Retrofit 2 ошибка Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Имею обычный json ответ сервера.
Пример: **{"id":58339}**

Но при запуске приложения возникает ошибка, что ожидался массив, но в ответе объект.
Насколько я понимаю, что приложению нужен массив объектов (пример: **[{"id":58339}]**)
Как мне работать с обычным json (**{"id":58339}**)?
Пример кода:
`@GET("/api/catalog/get-product")
    Call<List<ProductModel>> getProduct(@Query("id") String id);`

```
 private List<ProductModel> product;
 public  String productId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    this.productId = intent.getStringExtra(CatalogAdapter.PRODUCT_ID);

    App.getApi().getProduct(this.productId).enqueue(new Callback<ProductModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductModel>> call, Response<List<ProductModel>> response) {
            if (response.body() !=null) {
            product.addAll(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductModel>>call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Нет соединения с интернетом", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

И сама модель

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductModel {
   @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запрашиваете массив, указывая `List<ProductModel>`, так как у вас один объект нужно запрашивать просто `ProductModel`.

Comment: Хорошо.
Делаю так  Call<ProductModel> в запросе и в контроллере.
Но не понимаю как в контроллере загрузить данные в модель/
Раньше я таким образом загружал данные
 private List<ProductModel> product;
         product.addAll(response.body());

Comment: не понял вопроса

Comment: @VitautHryharovich, без All - Вы получили и добавляете один продукт: `product.add(response.body());`

Comment: Сейчас такая ошибка  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: у вас этот list не проинициализрован, он null, вы как код вообще пишите?

Comment: Вроде разобрался.
Добавил   product = new ArrayList<>();